# grails belongsTo incorrect references -> delete Problems

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Say we have two GORM-classes

```
class Team {
    static hasMany = [users: User]
    User createdBy // User who created this Team
}
class User {
    static belongsTo = [team: Team]
}
```

Grails mistakenly associates the createBy-User with the Team.
If I delete the team Grails cascades the delete to the createdBy-User, which is not intended!

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Team {
    static hasMany = [users: User]
    User createdBy // User who created this Team

 static mapping = {
            createdBy(cascade: 'none')  //only save and update cascade is allowed
            user cascade:'all-delete-orphan'  //remove other user references 
    }

}
```

I hope you have got ur solution!